# Elevation dataset appears to have come with all of the Eastings wrong

Tags: coordinate-system, dem, coordinates, vector-grid

I'm working with QGIS 3.12, trying to create a basemap of a mine site in Alberta for an env sci related project.  I downloaded the 20k ASCII DEM from Altalis and imported the .gnp layer; which is a collection of vector points with XYZ values and a FID.

The northings are all correct the eastings all put the point layer in Saskatchewan.  The coordinates of the center of my map are going to be 445834 E 5698420.N, UTM 12N, but the eastings in the layer which I downloaded all start in the 70s.  That said, the features all appear to line up with what I'm seeing on google earth, its just that their coordinates claim that these features are in Saskatchewan instead of Alberta. An example point from the .gnp below

FID 1098  X 708435.396  Y 5707399.9185 Z 904.11487

Comment: What is the Lat/Long of FID 1098? Can you post a link to where you got the DEM?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se. Can you say what happens when you check points using `gdaldem` on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [metadata](https://www.altalis.com/altalis/files/download?fileUUID=f36d8ca5-5f89-4e73-84d8-053b16c7510c) - the CRS is NAD_1983_10TM_AEP_Forest ([EPSG:3400](https://epsg.io/3400))

When brought into QGIS in this CRS, the data displays correctly:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why I wasn't grasping that yesterday but thank you.